# Why isn't least least squares used in finite elements?

Tags: least-squares, newton-raphson, gaussian-elimination

In finite elements, we generally use Gauss elimination or Newton-Raphson for solving the system of equations. Often the poor quality of mesh leads to an ill-conditioned global stiffness matrix or sometimes a degenerate element stiffness matrix.
While I understand that least-squares is used when we have an over-determined system. The least-squares can certainly be used in finite elements. https://amath.colorado.edu/pub/fosls/hyp1.pdf

Do you think least-squares in finite elements can fix problems that arises due to poor-mesh quality?

Comment: Maybe your question should be posted or migrated in the Engineering SE section.

Comment: oh, they have an engineering stack exchange. I didn't know that. btw how can I migrate it?

Comment: I've flagged the questions for a moderator intervention on that. I hope they can migrate the question with my answer. Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, we don't migrate questions unless a very strong case can be made for migration.  However, you are free to delete an unanswered question and reask the question elsewhere (or to simply ask the question elsewhere, making note that you asked it here, first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such kind of application for LS in FEM, but of course the problem arising from a poor quality of the mesh, which is an unavoidable approximation for a certain physical problem, can't be overcome throughout a different method to solve numerically the mathematical problem which is affected by a different kind of approximation. Therefore, for that reason the answer is no, least-squares in finite elements can't fix problems that arises due to poor-mesh quality.